# Setting up search interface in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have read how to setup search interface on google dev guide from here
http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

I was able to replicate it with activities. But, my application uses navigation drawer and fragments. One of my fragments need to implement an actionbar search that shows suggestions as the user type. I was able to setup search view for that particular fragment. But, I am still not sure how to implement `onNewIntent()` and how to set searchable configuration on manifest file. Is it at all possible to implement search interface with fragments. If so, can someone please provide code samples or links for reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`OnNewIntent()` always get called for `singleTop/Task` activities except for the first time when activity is created. At that time `onCreate` is called.

You can invoke `onNewIntent` always by putting it into `onCreate` method like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  //code
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to override onNewIntent() on a fragment?

Comment: No, there is no `onNewFragment` on `Fragment`